# How to process a cell array with different number of delimiters

Tags: matlab

> Error using split
>
> Element 5 of the text contains 4 delimiters while the previous elements have 5. All elements must contain the same number of delimiters.

```
str = split(s4, ",");
```

```matlab
'15:54:58.882",tscompute1,"524,288",bytes,"intel_rdt"'
'15:54:58.882",tscompute1,"294,912",bytes,"intel_rdt"'
'15:54:58.882",tscompute1,"786,432",bytes,"intel_rdt"'
'15:54:58.882",tscompute1,"491,520",bytes,"intel_rdt"'
'15:54:58.882",tscompute1,0,bytes,"intel_rdt"'
'15:54:58.882",tscompute1,0,bytes,"intel_rdt"'
```

I am getting an error as mentioned above while using split() function to split a cell array of strings with different number of delimiters. Provided is a sample data.

Comment: Where is your data coming from?  If it's a file then you should read it using `readtable` which will automatically handle the split for you.  You will find that the 3rd column are char's not numbers, but you can convert that yourself (which you'd need to do using your above approach anyway.

Comment: Data is collected from a system activity and stored in elastic search database. Moreover, readtable doesn't work as data is in a csv file.

Comment: Your data are poorly formated, if you can try to resolve the problem before. But if it's not your data you could use a regexp split: `B= regexp(string(s4),',(?!\d{2})','split')`

Comment: @obchardon Data formatting is not in my hands. I wish could have formatted before hand. However, I will try your advice.

Comment: @Yogesh, `readtable` works perfectly fine for a `csv` file.

Comment: Do you really have an odd number of `"` per line? An initial `"` seems to be missing in every line. Can you post the actual csv file from which those data are read?

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is that (I assume) `s4` is your cell, so you need to alliteratively access each string within `s4` (with curly braces `{}`).

```
str = [];
for i = 1:length(s4)
    str = [str; split(s4{i}, ",")];
end
```

[Here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/split.html) is the MATLAB reference Document for `split`. To read more about how cells work, read [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html?searchHighlight=cells&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) MATLAB Document page.

However, if your cell is Mx1, all you would need to do is transpose the cell to make it 1xM in order to load it completely into `split`.

```
s4 = tranpose(s4);
str = split(s4, ",");
```

Comment: As per the doc that you reference, `split` can take a cell array as an input.

Comment: My apologies. You are correct. However, you can still use the method above to iterate through each cell value to get the strings...

Comment: I think that it's more a "regexp" problem, where Yogesh would like to avoid to split the string for this grayed out comma : '15:54:58.882",tscompute1,"491`,`520",bytes,"intel_rdt"'

Comment: @obchardon Yes this is what I am after.